# Adding title groups to select options

Tags: html

currently working on an assignment and trying to code it to have titles as shown in the picture. Current code looks like this:

```
<section for="Pick up Location">Pick up Location:</label>
    <br><br>
    <select id="Pick up" name="Pick up">
      <option selected disabled>Hogwarts</option>
      <option value="Dining Hall">Dining Hall</option>
      <option value="Chamber of Secrets">Chamber of Secrets</option>
      <option selected disabled>Other</option>
      <option value="Forbidden Forest">Forbidden Forest</option>
      <option value="Hagrid's Shack">Hagrid's Shack</option>
    
    </select>
```

[Picture of what I need for formatting, Hogwarts and Other is how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dsaz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had it, just have to take the `selected` off of the 2 disabled options!

```html
<label for="Pick up Location">Pick up Location:</label>

<br><br>

<select id="Pick up" name="Pick up">
  <option disabled>Hogwarts</option>
  <option value="Dining Hall">Dining Hall</option>
  <option value="Chamber of Secrets">Chamber of Secrets</option>
  <option disabled>Other</option>
  <option value="Forbidden Forest">Forbidden Forest</option>
  <option value="Hagrid's Shack">Hagrid's Shack</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it more indented like how it is in the picture?

Comment: Why dont you try it by putting in spaces or padding